# Page fills window with content filling the gap

Tags: html, iframe, height, footer

I am currently building a website at http://grapevineiow.org/m_inspireblog.html. This website has a header and footer. The page I have linked to above features a blog in an `iframe`. Clearly the blog is far too long to fit into the page as one continuous piece of content, so scrollbars are required.

However, this is where there is a problem. I want to keep the scrollbars on the blog (so users can scroll through it), but I want the page to fill the window exactly, so the header and footer take up the minimum space needed. The header is fine, but the footer is being a problem.

I have tried:

- Setting the height of the `body` and `html` to `100%` in CSS.
- Setting the height of the `content` to `100%` in CSS, but that made the `content` fill the window.
- Styling the footer as `height:auto 0` in CSS.

...but none of these have worked.

I would like to be able to solve this problem using just CSS if possible, but I'm open to using HTML if needed. I would like to avoid Javascript.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the heights of the header and footer, you can achieve this by setting both top and bottom on the middle area like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #f09;
}
#content{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
    background: #f90;
}
#content iframe{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #90f;
}
</style>

<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">
    <iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```