# DIV tag height won't stretch to fill parent space

Tags: jquery, css, html, height

I'm trying to get a nested DIV tag, containing an Object tag, to stretch to its parent container remaining space.

What I have is header-content-footer template consisting of 3 DIV tags. The content DIV has an object containing another HTML page. The header and footer's height are set to absolute pixel values. I'd like the content DIV to take up the remaining space. Whatever I do, it seems the best I can come up with is making the DIV content tag to 100% of the screen height. Here's the code:

```
<body>
<div id="pageWrap">
<div id="page">
    <div id="header" style="height:68px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#header").load('header.jsp');
            });
    </script>
    <div id="mapLocation" style="width:100%; height:100%; overflow:auto;">
    <object type="text/html" style="width:100%; height:100%;" data="top/index.html"></object>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#footer").load('footer.jsp');
        });
    </script>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Any solution is good, jQuery, CSS or other!

Thanks for the help

Ggilmann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this is the same as a question I answered a couple of weeks ago:
[Page fills window with content filling the gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284561/page-fills-window-with-content-filling-the-gap/12285338#12285338)

Comment: I tried the solution you gave in the other thread but I can't get it to work. It seems that the object that is contained in my content Div tag overrides the height and width properties and just becomes 100% of full screen, always.

Comment: Hard to say, there is probably a whole bunch of markup on your page that I don't know about! Try making a new clean page using only my markup and then add your object. If you're not stuck to xhtml strict you may want to try using an iframe instead?

Comment: Well, I ended up using a variation of this solution so I'll flag this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you are giving aboslute positions for your header and footer then could you just use percentage values?

something like:

```
#header {
height:20%;
}

#footer {
height: 20%;
}

#div {
height: 60%;
}
```

Comment: Problem is, my header and footer height are set through an external css and I have no control over that css. Otherwise, that's probably what i would've done. Thanks!

Comment: If you include your own CSS after the external CSS you have precedence and can overwrite any styles easily by adding the above.

Comment: as henrik said you could use inline css to define the height unless in the external css the declaration !important  is used

Comment: From what I can see, this completely overrides the external style right? Is there a way to inherit the style and just add some style elements?

Comment: Think I replied too fast on that one, I seem to be having some problems with defining my own style..

Comment: I've got the override working now. Problem was that I'm loading a jsp file in both my header and footer. In these files, there are also tags with header and footer ids. So when I was overriding the style in the main html file, those items has this new style applied to them. I added the height % inline and now it works.

Comment: However, this does not give a satisfactory solution. when working with small resolution or when the window is resized, the header and footer become ridiculously small and parts of it disappear. So I'd really like to find a solution where the header and footer are fixed height and the content is fitted to what space is left on the screen